# javascript populating values from another variables

Tags: javascript, html

Hello all i am using a javascript to populate the values . i am using this script

```
String Vegs[]= request.getParameterValues("Vegs");
String qty_carrot=request.getParameter("quantity_carrot");
String qty_tomato=request.getParameter("quantity_tomato");
String qty_cabbage=request.getParameter("quantity_cabbage");
String qty[];
qty[0]=qty_carrot;
qty[1]=qty_tomato;
qty[2]=qty_cabbage;
```

but it says error the local variable qty is not initialized yet ..

also when i change the code to this

```
String qty[]=new array(3);
qty[0]=qty_carrot;
qty[1]=qty_tomato;
qty[2]=qty_cabbage;
```

It says array cannot be resolved to a type

Stack trace: @aravind

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create array like this:

```
String qty[] = new String[3];//<-- 3 is the size of array, you may change it
```

Comment: @user1799574, your post is scriplet in jsp and not JavaScript array! Give a try to my posted answer.

Comment: Yes i did try that it says type mismatch cannot convert from string to string[]

Comment: @user1799574, can you post the stack trace, that will be helpful

Comment: where do i add that String qty[]=new array(3); ? sorry i am new to jsp

Comment: added the stack trace

Comment: @user1799574, its new String[3]; not this new array(3);

Comment: Thanks it worked I had put new String(3) changing that to String[3] solved